# Link 2 fields from a model in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am relatively new to Django and I made a Todo list where user can add a task and mark if its completed. I added a form field of priorities which is a radio select widget. Based on the priority the task field will have red, orange or green color.

The radio buttons appear correctly and I cant post a task without giving an input priority. But the priority is always taken as default(high).

I tried a couple of things to change and display the priorities but nothing worked.
I believe something in the views.py is to be modified to make it work but due to my lack of experience I cannot put a finger on it.

## Views.py

```
@require_POST
def addTodo(request):
    form = TodoForm(request.POST)

    #print(request.POST['text'])

    if form.is_valid():
        new_todo = Todo(text = request.POST['text'])
        new_todo.save()

    for item in form:


    return redirect('index')

def completeTodo(request, todo_id):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
    todo.complete = True
    todo.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

## form.py

```
    from django import forms

prior_choice =[('high','High'),('mod','Mod'),('low','Low')]
class TodoForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length = 40,
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs= {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter todo e.g. Delete junk files', 'aria-label': 'Todo', 'aria-describedby':'add-btn'}))
    priority = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=prior_choice))
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    task_priority = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='high')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

## index.html

```html
<ul class="list-group t20">
            {% for todo in todo_list %}
              {% if todo.task_priority == 'high'%}
            
                <a href=" {% url 'complete' todo.id %}" ><li class="list-group-item " style="background-color: red;"> {{ todo.text}}</li></a>
              
              {%elif todo.task_priority == 'mod'%}
                <a href=" {% url 'complete' todo.id %}" ><li class="list-group-item " style="background-color: orange;"> {{ todo.text}}</li></a>
              {%elif todo.task_priority == 'low'%}  
                <a href=" {% url 'complete' todo.id %}" ><li class="list-group-item " style="background-color: yellow;"> {{ todo.text}}</li></a>
              {%else%}
              <div class="todo-completed"> <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: green;"> {{ todo.text}}</li></div>    
              {%endif%}
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

[Heres a screenshot of the output app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcm8V.png)

Please help me link the radio button to a task in the list and display accordingly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a good place for a `ModelForm`, and maybe a `CreateView`.

Comment: You never use the priority from your form, you only set the text.

Comment: For just assigning priorities? Can we implement any conditional / iterative statement to assign the priorities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your view. While you are creating your `Todo` object you are not passing the priority.

```
       new_todo = Todo(text = request.POST['text'], task_priority = request.POST['priority'])
```

The code above solves your problem. But I DO NOT RECOMMEND it. You are not leveraging the Django forms. Please use Django `forms.cleaned_data` to get parameters instead of `request.POST` or use ModelForm which will allow you to save from form instance directly.

---

**Model Change Advice**

However this is not how i would like solve the issue. You can change your model as following to have more djangoic way of doing it:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Todo(models.Model):
    PRIORITY_NONE = 0
    PRIORITY_LOW = 1
    PRIORITY_MODERATE = 2
    PRIORITY_HIGH = 3
    PRIORITIES = (
        (PRIORITY_NONE, _('')),
        (PRIORITY_LOW, _('Low')),
        (PRIORITY_MODERATE, _('Moderate')),
        (PRIORITY_HIGH, _('High')),
    )
    ...
    task_priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PRIORITIES, default=PRIORITY_NONE)
```

You may need to change your form with the choices `Todo.PRIORITIES`. Also you may want to use `ModelForm` which will make things much easier for you.

Comment: Hi @scriptmonster I made the changes as you suggested. The default null value works but somehow when I check the via superuser the priorities still lists the default (null). The priorities are still not being linked to the individual task.

Comment: request.POST for task_priority fixes the problem but it would like to understand the 2nd approach better

Comment: First of all i got the question wrong, than i edited. If you create a ModelForm, it will create your form with the choices without effort. And you do not let your field to be empty which will help you filter with ease. Furthermore making all of your choices class attribute you can make comparison with a human readable variables. In your views you can use the priority attributes to compare. Also you limit the values with the choices. In your implementation you could write `high` to the field in one place and `HIGH` in other which are not the same. This list can go longer :)